# Are the squares in my graph paper too small?

Tags: dnd-5e, battle-map

I'm starting my first campaign with so friends of mine, and I think my graph paper is too small.
I mean, 4 squares equals 1 inch so... Also the paper has 35 tiles in width.
I'm using regular office-store graph paper. Could you say if my graph paper is good enough?
Could you also recommend some more... friendly, graph paper for tabletop-roleplaying?

Comment: This question could be improved by adding some details about what exactly you intend to use the paper for.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to use it as a battle mat with miniatures and such, then you might run into scale issues. Most miniatures assume a scale of 1 inch representing 5 feet, which your office graph paper would have trouble with (unless you find and use much, much smaller miniatures).

However, that's about the only downside to using regular graph paper. If you're just using it to make maps or to show those maps to your players, office graph paper will work just fine.

If you're looking for something larger for the use of miniatures, I can't recommend any particular brand, partly because this isn't the place for that and partly because there are just so many and various solutions available. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g1KAE0sI-M) demonstrates several of the different types available.